# PHP FPDF Multiple Multicell height adjusting

Tags: php, fpdf

Im trying to make the height of my multicell and other cells adjust to the highest height of a multicell.[image]

this is what my pdf looks like now using the code below. the only problem is i cannot adjust the description column to align with the highest MULTICELL which is SUBCODE. Both SUBCODE and DESCRIPTION are MULTICELL the rest are plain cell.

```
$h1 = $pdf->GetMultiCellHeight(85, 5, $r->subdesc, $border=null, $align='J');
$h2 = $pdf->GetMultiCellHeight(35, 5, $r->subcode, $border=null, $align='J');
$height = ($h1 > $h2) ? $h1 : $h2;

                $pdf->Cell(20,$height,$r->section,1,0,'L');
                $pdf->Cell(15,$height,$r->code,1,0,'L');
                $subcode = ($r->wga == 1) ? '*'.$r->subcode : $r->subcode;

                $x = $pdf->GetX();
                $y = $pdf->GetY();
                $pdf->MultiCell(35, 5, iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $r->subcode), 1);
                $pdf->SetXY($x + 35, $y);

                $x = $pdf->GetX();
                $y = $pdf->GetY();
                $pdf->MultiCell(85, 5, iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $r->subdesc), 1,'L', false);
                $pdf->SetXY($x + 85, $y);

                $pdf->Cell(10,$height,$r->units,1,0,'C');
                $pdf->Cell(10,$height,$r->grade,1,0,'C');
                $pdf->Cell(20,$height,$r->remark,1,0,'C');
                $pdf->Ln();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:
1. Draw empty cell with bottom border (with correct height) and multicells without bottom borderline

```
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();              
$pdf->Cell(195, $height, "", 1, 0, 'B');
$pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
$pdf->Cell(20,$height,$section,1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(15,$height,$code,1,0,'L');
$subcode = ($wga == 1) ? '*'.$subcode : $subcode;
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->MultiCell(35, 5, iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $subcode), 'L,T,R');
```

2. Even multicells lines:

```
$height = ($h1 > $h2) ? $h1 : $h2;
$subcode = ($wga == 1) ? '*'.$subcode : $subcode; //have to be done here
if($h1<$height){
  for($i=$h1; $i<=$height; $i++)
  $subdesc .= "\n";
}elseif($h2<$height){
  for($i=$h2; $i<=$height; $i++)
  $subcode .= "\n";
}
```